# Регулярное выражение в Гугл форме. Удаление лишних пробелов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-forms

Необходимо написать регулярное выражение, чтобы при заполнении анкеты, не допускались пробелы вначале и в конце. Получается сделать вначале строки, чтобы была ошибка на пробел: `(^\s)`, но как сделать и для окончания строки...

Пример:

[image: Форма]

Comment: Там не только пробелы могут быть, но и другие, например отследить можно так `(^\s+|\s+$)` в начале или конце.

Comment: Этого более чем достаточно:) Большое спасибо за информацию)!

Comment: А можно ли как то добавить, чтобы между словами был только один пробел? т.е. не было иван__иван? а лишь иван_иван

Comment: Ну например так: `(?>(^[^\s+]))+(\w+(\s{1}\w+))+(?>([^\s+]+$))` - если будет в начале пробел или более, не пустит, если будет в конце пробел и более не пустит, если не будет не в начале не в конце, а разрыв будет превышать 1 пробел, не пустит.

Comment: Хмм..ввожу Ваше выражение в условие, пишет, что: "Введите корректное выражение":(

Comment: Обновил регулярку выше, попробуйте теперь.

Comment: (?>(^[^\s+]))+(\w+(\s{1}\w+))+(?>([^\s+]+$)) - если вставлять частями выражение, то безошибочно указывает на центральную часть выражения, первая и последняя выдается с ошибкой.